# Sending tones via a manual process with Twilio

Tags: twilio

Our call center deals with businesses and we use Twilio to make our calls. However, many businesses have a menu to navigate before we get to talk to someone. How can I create a 10-key pad on our end and use it to send menu selections to the call we are connected with?

I know about the senddigits attribute on Dialing numbers with Twilio, but this sends preprogrammed tones. We have no way of knowing what the tones need to be until we are connected and in the menu, so this won't work.

I've been through the API pretty thoroughly and can't seem to find anything relating to this.

If there is nothing, is there another software that anyone can recommend that allows for making calls out, generating recordings of calls and allows me to send keytones manually after the call has been started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the digits attribute of the 'Play' tag.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play#attributes-digits

Each 'w' character tells Twilio to wait 0.5 seconds instead of playing a digit.

Comment: This is getting close. It's on the Play tag and that would be in precoded files. Can I trigger the play tag with digits on click? Because we are calling many different companies every day and all of their menus are different, I need to basically build a little 10 key pad in html and then on click of each number play that numbers dtmf tone.

Comment: If you're in a browser using Twilio Client you can use connection.sendDigits, an example of an HTML keypad is here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/twilio-client-browser-soft-phone.  Or if it's not a client call use the call modification API to redirect a live phone call to the Play digits flow. https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I am understanding your problem, could you not us MP3s of DTMF tones (http://jetcityorange.com/dtmf/) and PLAY to send the tones after the call has started?